# Javascript validation for windows machine name

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to write a regular expression to validate the windows machine as per the Microsoft windows naming convention.
There are some reserved words provided by Microsoft, those reserved words are allowed in machine name or not?
if not allowed, then I am using  following regex to validate it

```
@"(?=^(?![.]))(?=(?![\W_]+$))(?=(?!\d+$))(?=(?:(?!ANONYMOUS|AUTHENTICATED USER|BATCH|BUILTIN|CREATOR GROUP|CREATOR GROUP SERVER|CREATOR OWNER|CREATOR OWNER SERVER|DIALUP|DIGEST AUTH|INTERACTIVE|INTERNET|LOCAL|LOCAL SYSTEM|NETWORK|NETWORK SERVICE|NT AUTHORITY|NT DOMAIN|NTLM AUTH|NULL|PROXY|REMOTE INTERACTIVE|RESTRICTED|SCHANNEL AUTH|SELF|SERVER|SERVICE|SYSTEM|TERMINAL SERVER|THIS ORGANIZATION|USERS|WORLD).)*$)^[^\\/:*?""<>|]+$"
```

but it should allow LOCALIZATION as machine name and should not allow LOCAL. But whenever I use LOCALIZATION it gives error.

I need to write a regex which should allow LOCALIZATION but should not allow LOCAL as machine name.

what changes do i have to make in above regex?? Thanks

Comment: I think you can just use `^LOCAL$` in the negative lookahead.

Comment: I used following regex to make it work : @"^(?!\s)(?=^(?![.]))(?=(?![\W_]+$))(?=(?!\d+$))(?=^(?!(LOCAL|ANONYMOUS|AUTHENTICATED USER|BATCH|BUILTIN|CREATOR GROUP|CREATOR GROUP SERVER|CREATOR OWNER|CREATOR OWNER SERVER|DIALUP|DIGEST AUTH|INTERACTIVE|INTERNET|LOCAL SYSTEM|NETWORK|NETWORK SERVICE|NT AUTHORITY|NT DOMAIN|NTLM AUTH|NULL|PROXY|REMOTE INTERACTIVE|RESTRICTED|SCHANNEL AUTH|SELF|SERVER|SERVICE|SYSTEM|TERMINAL SERVER|THIS ORGANIZATION|USERS|WORLD)$))^[^\\/:*?""<>|]+$" .It is working fine for me now.

Comment: But now i want to prevent user from entering the trailing whitespaces. Can you help me with that? I used [ \t]+$ and \s but it didn't work. Please help me out. I need to make changes in the same regex.